# With PHPUnit how does one run initialization code before any tests are run?

Tags: phpunit

Currently we run code to setup the database in setUpBeforeClass. However this runs before every test class is tested. Is it possible to have code run once before any tests are run, and maybe run some code when all tests are complete too?

Comment: I have the same need : initiate my database before tests are launched. Can you post an answer with your detailed solution ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is precisely what the bootstrap file is designed to handle. By default PHPUnit will execute the code in `bootstrap.php` in the current directory. You can use the [`phpunit.xml`](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html) configuration file or the [`--bootstrap`](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions) command-line switch to point to a different file.

This file is executed exactly once before trying to locate the tests to be run. It allows you to set up an include path, autoloader, constants, etc. before instantiating or running any tests.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Someone mentioned this to me yesterday. I don't know why I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Kris's comment that you want to avoid this sort of behavior, but if you need to, perhaps you could do something like this:

```
class My_PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       // Insert your one time setup scripts here
    }
}
```

Then make sure your tests extend My_PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase instead of PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.

Comment: As I understand it, this would be equivalent to setUpBeforeClass

Comment: Actually, all test cases are instantiated before any test methods are executed--one per test method per data set, and one additional instance per method with a `@dataProvider`. If you override the constructor you must make sure to accept and pass along the three parameters as well.

Comment: @SubOne, this is not equivalent to setUpBeforeClass, its a statuc function

Answer (score -5):

Why would you want to do that? Unit tests should be independent of each other, and thus should all preconditions also be restored to the same state before every test is run.

If you feel the need to have an initialization method that runs once for the entire suite, your tests are probably not set up right.

Comment: We want to bring the database up and tear it down once, not for every test. We've got transactions in place to isolate the tests.

Comment: Whilst I agree with you in principle, there are many legitimate reasons for doing this, one such example is what @SubOne mentioned. I'm testing Laravel through Travis.CI and I need to run the database creation scripts to ensure it has the right environment for testing.